# CV Question regarding languages and military service

Tags: resume, language

I have two questions.

1. Where should I include my military service (compulsory in my country) on the CV. Would you put it under work experience?
2. Should I include so-called "dead" languages (ie. Latin) as a language. I studied it at school but for obvious reasons cannot speak it.

Comment: What would be the obvious reason you can't speak it? If you're listing it as a language I would expect that you can.

Comment: you are supposed to translate texts but almost noone speaks it fluently apart from some monks in Italy. I am just not sure about. I picked it instead of learning French/Russian which were the other 2 choices. So I really studied it but cannot converse in the language

Comment: A CV is a way to show, through your previous _activities_ that you are skilled for the job you're applying to. So list all experiences/skills relevant for the job, nothing more. Have your military service made you fitter for the job? I guess so (learning how to obey hierarchy, manage people, be reliable/on time…), so list it. But if not, don't. Idem for Latin.

Answer (score 6):

List the military experience chronologically, highlighting relevant experience while there, list the language under "additional skills", but only if relevant.

Comment: +1 presumably the OP got paid for it so it's a job, just a slightly less dangerous one than working in an office :)

Comment: I might also add knowing a dead language is rarely relevant when job hunting as it adds no benefit to the company.

Comment: @SaggingRufus knowledge of a classic language tends to correlate with an overall educational sophistication and curiosity which can be of benefit.  And these do still have modern relevance from time to time.

Comment: @ChrisStratton At least in the UK, knowledge of a classical language correlates with nothing more than going to a posh school.

Comment: Such schooling may very well be of (perceived) relevance; also note that the question cannot be about the UK which has not had compulsory military service since circa 1960 unless the candidate is at least in their 70's

Comment: Scientia est potentia

Comment: @SaggingRufus not always. In Italy there are some type of high schools where Latin and Greek are mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

Military service shows you have learnt discipline, organisational skills, teamwork and many other virtues that are transferable to other fields.  Absolutely mention it.

Latin shows good education so if you're in any kind of intellectual field (ie anything that requires a university degree or higher) definitely put it in.

Answer (score 1):

1) No. Or better, you just need to write something like "military service completed" since the risk for the employer is that he hire you and after a couple of months (or more) you need to leave to your military duty. In Italy we had the same problem and in the CV we simply add the phrase to state we are done with our military duty (one year at the time). Eventually you can add where and with which posting.

2) No, this should be clear from the school you attended on your CV unless you studied it as hobby, but it is not the case. Again, in Italy if you write on your CV that you attended a scientific high school ("Liceo scientifico" in Italian) is implicit that you studied Latin.

I used Italy as example since I am Italian, but I suppose that every employer of your country know what you study in school and, since it is compulsory, that you need to do you military duty at some point in life, normally just after the school.